# Entity Data Model Wizard not creating tables in EDMX file

Tags: ado.net, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying the database first approach by creating an ADO.NET Entity Data Model using the wizard with the Adventureworks2012 DB.

Testing DB connection works, and the connection string is added to the App.Config.

I'm selecting all the tables except the ones marked as (dbo) `AWBuildVersion`, `DatabaseLog`, and `ErrorLog`.

When the wizard finishes the `.edmx` file is blank, and if I view the file in XML view the `EntityContainer` is empty.

After the model is created it returns this error in the output window:

> *Unable to generate the model because of the following exception: 'The
>   table AdventureWorks2012.Production.Document is referenced by a
>   relationship, but cannot be found.*

I'm using VS 2010 & .NET Framework 4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Entity Framework does not know how to deal with data types like hierarchyid set on a table field. I removed the Production.Document table for the list of entities to include solving my problem.

Note also that this reference below was for Adventureworks 2008R2 with EF version 1.0 from Code Plex SQL Sever, and I am using Adventureworks 2012 from the same CodePlex site using EF version 4.4.

Reference: http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AW2008Details

Note: EF 1.0 Compatibility Issues

The Entity Framework team would like us to let you know that AdventureWorks2008 is a little bit ahead of the curve in terms of the Katmai features it uses. Some datatypes in AdventureWorks2008 (such as hierarchyid and geometry) are not supported in the entity framework. The workaround is to exclude tables like Production.Document from your model if possible since there is currently no support for the hierarchyid datatype in Entity Framework 1.0. Unfortunately the Entity Framework tooling which updates your model from the database will pull in tables like Production.Document even if they were specifically excluded when the model was created, so use of that feature on AdventureWorks2008R2 is not supported at this time. We look forward to a follow-on release of Entity Framework which has full SQL Server 2008 type support.
Last edited May 25, 2010 at 2:22 PM by bonniefe, version 17

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get around this *IF* you're trying to learn from this example and not doing anything meaningful.  I deleted the foreign keys to the offending table and removed it and was able to succesfully get

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck [Allow Nulls] Check-boxes (in the table design) for all the foreign keys of the not created Tables (Tables not converted to the model).

[image]

Then you can update your model to retrieve those tables by doing the following steps:-

Step 1 - Right click some where in your .EDMX file's design (i.e. Model1.EDMX [Diagram1].
Step 2 - then from the Context Menu select / Update Model from Database....
Step 3 - then select "Add"
Step 4 - then expend "Tables" Check-Boxes and select your desired tables (tables not created first time).
Step 5 - then click Finish button.
Step 6 - Save the the solution and hope everything will be Ok.

[image]

Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Good luck.